# Why the length of RS code is $2^m -1$

Tags: coding-theory

In 1960, Reed and Solomon suggest the codeword for a message $[x_0\ x_1\ \ldots\ x_k]$ as follows:

$$[P_{(0)}\ P_{(\alpha)}\ P_{(\alpha^2)}\ \cdots\ P_{(\alpha^{2^m-1})}]$$

Where

$$P_{(t)}=x_0 +x_1t+x_2t^2+\cdots +x_{k-1}t^{k-1}$$

And $\alpha$ is a generator of $GF(2^m)$. So the length of the codeword would be $2^m$.

However, today the RS code is usually considered a code of the length $2^m-1$. Why? And what is redundant?

Comment: The cyclic version of RS code has length $2^m-1$. It can be viewed as coming by evaluating polynomials at the points $1=\alpha^0$, $\alpha^1$, $\alpha^2$, $\ldots$, $\alpha^{2^m-2}$. It is pointless to include $\alpha^{2^m-1}$, because $\alpha^{2^m-1}=\alpha^0=1$ It is possible to also evaluate polynomials at zero (you seem to be doing just that). That works just as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You mean if $P_{(0)}$ is included the code wouldn't be cyclic? And there wouldn't be a generator polynomial like the BCH interpretation of the RS code?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. If we include $P(0)$ then we lose the abilitiy to use a generator polynomial

Comment: Ok. How about MDS property. Does in both interpretations the MDS property hold?

Comment: Yes. Both versions are MDS.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about it? I have added a new [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358277/how-original-rs-codes-and-the-corresponding-bch-codes-are-related) about it.