# How original RS codes and the corresponding BCH codes are related?

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

In 1960, Reed and Solomon suggest the codeword for a message $[x_0\ x_1\ \ldots\ x_k]$ as follows:

$$[P_{(0)}\ P_{(\alpha)}\ P_{(\alpha^2)}\ \cdots\ P_{(\alpha^{2^m-1})}]$$

Where

$$P_{(t)}=x_0 +x_1t+x_2t^2+\cdots +x_{k-1}t^{k-1}$$
How is this equivalent to the BCH code generated by the following polynomial?

$$g{(x)} = \prod_{i=1}^{n-k} x-\alpha^i$$

Comment: I have searched and it was only briefly explained in Wikipedia and I didn't understand it. I also don't understand why in BCH version we can't have $P_{(0)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion is not quite correct: $[P_{(0)}\ P_{(\alpha)}\ P_{(\alpha^2)}\ \cdots\ P_{(\alpha^{2^m-1})}]$ is a codeword in an *extended* cyclic (Reed-Solomon) code which is also an *extended* cyclic
BCH code. The $P_{(0)}$ symbol is an overall parity check on the remaining
symbols which do, in fact, form a cyclic BCH code in the sense that
the corresponding codeword polynomials are multiples of the generator
polynomial of a cyclic code which has $n-k$ consecutive powers of $\alpha$
as its roots.

Specifically, if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ or less
with coefficients in $\mathbb F_{2^m}$ and $\alpha$ is a primitive
element of this field, then
$[P(1)\ P(\alpha)\ P(\alpha^2)\ \cdots\ P(\alpha^{2^m-2})]$
is a codeword in a *cyclic* $[2^m-1,k]$ Reed-Solomon code.
The corresponding codeword *polynomial* is
$$\hat{P}(z) = P(1) + P(\alpha)z + P(\alpha^2)z^2 + \cdots P\left(\alpha^{2^m-2}\right)z^{2^m-2}.$$
Think of $[P(1)\ P(\alpha)\ P(\alpha^2)\ \cdots\ P(\alpha^{2^m-2})]$
as the finite-field discrete Fourier transform of the vector
$[P_0\  P_1\ P_2\ \cdots \ P_{k-1}\  0 \ 0 \  \cdots \ 0]$.
The *inverse* discrete Fourier transform says that
$$P_i = \hat{P}\left(\alpha^{-i}\right) 
= \hat{P}\left(\alpha^{2^m-1-i}\right)$$ and since we know that
$P_{2^m-2}, P_{2^m-2}, \cdots, P_{k+1}, P_k$ all have value $0$, we deduce
that $$\hat{P}(\alpha) = \hat{P}(\alpha^2) = \cdots
= \hat{P}\left(\alpha^{2^m-1-k}\right) = 0,$$
that is, $\hat{P}(z)$ is a *multiple* of
$$g(z) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^m-1-k}(z-\alpha^i).$$

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Actually I understood and appreciate everything after the second paragraph. However, about the first paragraph if we have $P(0)$ , then it can not be considered as a form of Fourier transform since the equation $\alpha^i = 0$ holds for no $i$. Then how is it possible to have a BCH generator polynomial?

Comment: The $[2^m, k]$ extended cyclic Reed-Solomon codes over $\mathbb F_{2^m}$ are **not** cyclic codes of length $2^m$ except in the trivial cases $k = 0, 1, 2^m$. As I said in my first paragraph, the _equivalence_ that you seek between the definition of Reed-Solomon codes in the original Reed and Solomon paper and cyclic BCH codes does not exist. The answer to your question "Then how is it possible to have a BCH generator polynomial?" is that it is **not** possible.